# Why is the Jetpack Compose card radius corner not even

Tags: android-cardview, android-jetpack-compose

I'm having a `lazyColumn` that wrap items of

```
@Composable
fun MySimpleListItem(
    itemViewState: String,
    itemClickedCallback: (() -> Unit)? = null,
) {
    Card(
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(50.dp),
        backgroundColor = Color(0xFFFF0000),
    ) {
        Text(
            text = itemViewState,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(16.dp),
            style = TextStyle(fontSize = 32.sp),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
    }
}
```

Looks like the corner at the top and bottom is rounded differently. Did I do anything wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your cards height is too small to display the shape correctly. It should be at least twice as large as your radius

```
Card(
    modifier = Modifier.preferredHeight(100.dp),
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(50.dp),
    backgroundColor = Color(0xFFFF0000),
)
```

or set the radius of your shape in percent:

```
Card(
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(50),
    backgroundColor = Color(0xFFFF0000),
    )
```